# Saving Gestures as bitmap

Tags: android, gesture

I just want to know whether I can save the Gestures as bitmap in android from a layout. I had asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622484/saving-bitmap-image-using-gesture-draw) before but never got a reply

please help...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

we can save the gesture as bitmap

```
GestureOverlayView gestureView = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
        gestureView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(gestureView.getDrawingCache());
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "signature.png");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        //compress to specified format (PNG), quality - which is ignored for PNG, and out stream
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
        os.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have plans to do the same but havent implemented it. I did notice that there's the Guesture.toBitmap() method which, if works as advertised, seems like the ticket.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/Gesture.html#toBitmap%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29